# Jenkins Pipeline with Multibranch Workflows: Execute action on branch deletion

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

Is there a hook/post action, etc. in Jenkins when working with Multibranch Workflows Pipeline so that an action can be executed after (or just before) the branch is deleted?

I need to clean up some resources after branch has been removed, but google gives zero clues on that.

I could always have a hook from github side, but wondering is something similar in Jenkins:

- On branch create allocate resource X
- On branch delete de-allocate resource X

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested this, but there is a [multibranch-job-teardown-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/multibranch-job-tear-down-plugin) which should allow release of resources.

For the setup you might have to fall back on evaluating your build history to find out if this is the first run of a job. Checking `currentBuild.getPreviousBuild()` for `null` should help to discover this, allowing to allocate some resources.